# Templates and division

Tags: performance, templates, boost, mpfr

I am using a templated class in c++ and I am planning on ensuring compatibility with doubles and mpfr floats.  The only division that occurs in the program is division by 2.  The behavior for doubles and mpfr floats for division by 2 should be different because, in mpfr, I have direct access to the exponent.

Question: What do you suggest to result in the most efficient compiled code?

- I expect that a run-time solution checking the type of the templated variable would be inefficient.
- Boost's mpfr wrapper does not seem useful because it doesn't seem to use the mpfr_div_2ui command and would, instead, divide by the mpfr float with a value of 2.  I expect this to be slower than directly changing the exponent.
- I could use an overloaded command to deal with the two cases of mpfr floats and doubles.
- I could use some user-set #define flag that the user would need to set to use mpfr data types.
- Are there any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd check whether `number<mpfr_floatXXX>` doesn't already detect the optimization.

> Boost's mpfr wrapper does not seem useful because it doesn't seem to use the mpfr_div_2ui command and would, instead, divide by the mpfr float with a value of 2. I expect this to be slower than directly changing the exponent.

That expectation is not well founded. Simply check:

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/mpfr.hpp>

int main() {
    using namespace boost::multiprecision;

    mpfr_float_50 n ("787878787878");
    n /= 2;
}
```

Compiles into

```
mov rax, QWORD PTR fs:40
mov QWORD PTR [rsp+232], rax
xor eax, eax
lea rdi, [rsp+16]
call    mpfr_init2
cmp QWORD PTR [rsp+40], 0
xor ecx, ecx
mov edx, 10
lea rdi, [rsp+16]
call    mpfr_set_str
test    eax, eax
cmp QWORD PTR [rsp+40], 0
lea rsi, [rsp+16]
xor ecx, ecx
mov edx, 2
mov rdi, rsi
call    mpfr_div_ui
```

So, it isn't nearly as bad as you made it seem.

### Implementation

Here is my non-generic implementation:

```
mp::mpfr_float_50 div_2ui(mp::mpfr_float_50 const& f, unsigned i) {
    mp::mpfr_float_50 r;
    ::mpfr_div_2ui(
            r.backend().data(), 
            f.backend().data(),
            i,
            MPFR_RNDN);

    return r;
}
```

A generic implementation would look like:

```
template <typename T, typename Enable = void> struct is_mpfr : boost::mpl::false_ {};

template <unsigned digits10, mp::mpfr_allocation_type AllocationType, mp::expression_template_option ET>
struct is_mpfr<
        mp::number<mp::mpfr_float_backend<digits10, AllocationType>, ET >
    > : boost::mpl::true_ 
{};

template <typename T>
T div_2ui_impl(T f, unsigned i, boost::mpl::false_) {
    while (i--)
        f /= 2;
    return f;
}

template <typename Mpfr>
Mpfr div_2ui_impl(Mpfr f, unsigned i, boost::mpl::true_) {
    std::cout << "-- optimized --";
    Mpfr r;
    ::mpfr_div_2ui(r.backend().data(), f.backend().data(), i, MPFR_RNDN);
    return r;
}

template <typename T>
T div_2ui(T const &f, unsigned i) {
    return div_2ui_impl(f, i, is_mpfr<T> { });
}
```

### Live Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/09b139a282df0f54)</kbd>**

```
template <typename T>
void test() {
    T n("787878787878");
    n = arith::div_2ui(n, 1);
    std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << ": " << n << "\n";
}

int main() {
    std::cout << std::fixed;

    test<mp::mpfr_float_50>();
    test<mp::mpfr_float_100>();
    test<mp::cpp_int>();
    test<mp::cpp_dec_float_100>();
    test<mp::number<mp::gmp_int> >();
    test<mp::mpf_float_1000>();
}
```

Prints

```
-- optimized --test: 393939393939.000000
-- optimized --test: 393939393939.000000
test: 393939393939
test: 393939393939.000000
test: 393939393939
test: 393939393939.000000
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  You're right that I didn't look at the assembly (it has been many years since I've looked at assembly).  The call to mpfr_div_ui is supposed to optimize when the input is a constant power of 2; so perhaps the optimization is already happening.  I will try to search for conformation of this optimization.  My main concern was that boost would create a mpfr float to represent 2 and then divide by that float (I would expect that within mpfr, the corresponding call to be slower - but I don't have supporting evidence).

Comment: Anyhoops, added some generic dispatch wrapper for demo purposes